# Javascript to set an alphabetical letter equal to the one before

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I wanted to make a program in where we can say that every letter, is equal to the one before it, except - the letter **a**, which will be set to 0. However, as I am a beginner, Im not quite sure where to begin. I believe something such as a Javascript switch statement ought to do the task:

```
ar a,...,z;
switch (~~~~~~~) {
case 0:
    "a" = "0";
    break;
case 1:
    "b" = "a";
    break;
case 2:
    "c" = "b";
    break;
case n:
    "letter" = "letter before it";
    break;
    ...}
```

My **question** is how I can turn the Pseudo Code above into real code?

Comment: switch is probably the worst way to do it. Look into [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [String.prototype.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt). Then you just need to ensure what you have is a letter, find it's code and grab the one before, in case the letter is `a` simply assign 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically retrieve the previous letter by getting the ASCII code and reducing by 1:

```
function previousLetter(letter){
    if(letter == 'a') return 0;
    else return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0)-1)
}

> previousLetter('b')
'a'
> previousLetter('a')
0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able to understand how we would apply this to numbers:`function previousNumber(number){
    if(number == '1') return "b";
     return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0)-1)
}
`

Comment: You said you wanted to return the previous letter in alphabet, you did not describe anything about numbers. In the code below, `letter.charCodeAt(0)` returns the ASCII code (integer equivalent of character).

Comment: I never mentioned numbers, since it wasn't my initial step. My intention to map out the numbers to the letters. For example, map the letter b to 1, the letter c to 2, the d to. However, Im perplexed how to do such.

Comment: If this is what you want to do, you just have to substract the 97, which is the ASCII code of 'a'. So, `letter.charCodeAt(0)-97` will give you the sequence of each alphabet letter.

Comment: Thank you,but there might be a mistake I made: `function previousNumber(number){
    if(number == '1') return 0;
     else return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0)-97)
}`. Unfortunately, the code doesn't work.

Comment: If you want just to map the characters to the corresponding sequence index, then the following will work `function previousIntFromLetter(letter){ return (letter.charCodeAt(0)-97) }`. Otherwise, I think you should edit your question, instead of creating so many comments.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use case for every character. Just compare the ASCII value of the character to ASCII value -1 (which is the previous character)

```
str="a";
if(str.charCodeAt(0)==(str.charCodeAt(0)-1))
alert('true');
```

You can filter the ASCII value 97 (a) to be ignored for the comparison

Comment: Shame the example is `a` which the OP said would be `0` :)

Comment: and this compare them, it doesn't assign it the previous letter.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you, so I assume I could use the ASCII 'numerical' value of each letter to turn it into a number,therefore?

Answer (score 0):

You must put off the " symbol:

```
var a,...,z;
switch (~~~~~~~) {
case 0:
    a = "0";
    break;
case 1:
    b = a;
    break;
case 2:
    c = b;
    break;
case n:
    letter = "letter before it";
    break;
    ...}
```

This code, in case 1 (for example) set the variable b equal to variable a, but actually in this code all variables aren't initialized so allways be null, you must initialize it first like this:

```
a = "a";
```

or directly put in the correct case:ç

```
case 1:
    b = "a";
    break;
```